# Modify specific edge properties using cytoscape.js (Substantially edited on 2-15-24)

Tags: cytoscape.js

My objective is to programmatically draw a static diagram following a set of constraints (provided externally) and save that graphic to a file (in, say, PNG format). I have written code to read a graph in GML format and produce the Cytoscape output. The file I produced displays the graph successfully. (I don't see a way to attach the file.)
Following tutorial examples, I have created an html file on Windows 11 and added cytoscape.min.js into the same folder to display it. Here is a snapshot of part of the graph.
[Portion of my graph 109](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzFoz.png).
I want to make many changes to this graph, but for this question I'll focus on the following changes to the graph:

1. Move only the edge from AssetTp to CLnItm so it is vertical from the bottom of AssetTp to the top of CLnItm.
2. Move the third edge from the left on the bottom of AssetTp further right (past UoM) and make it vertical (it connects with another node that is outside this snapshot.)

I have previously edited the specification of a node, adding a style section to that node, specifying its width:

```
{ data: { id: '1', name: 'Party' }, position: {x: 412.000000,y: 512.000000 }, style: { 'width' : '200.000000'}},
```

I read on this site: https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-endpoints
about Edge endpoints. I tried editing the html file, adding a style section to the edge in question. When I double-clicked on the resulting file I was shown a blank page.
How, then, can I accomplish this?

Original:
{
data: {
id: '2-13',
source: '2',
target:'13'
}
},

Changed to:

{
data: {
id: '2-13',
source: '2',
target:'13'
},
style: {
source-endpoint: '90deg'
}
},

---

EDIT BEGINS HERE

---

Here is a simple cytoscape diagram.
[Diagram showing AssetTp(top),and UoM(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3fsz.png)

Something like this code snippet is what I want to add to the above file (after the Cytoscape json is defined, and before the end-of-script  line. It shows how I have hoped I would be able to position individual
edges. Here is the html/css/js file used to create that diagram:

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [{
      data: {
        id: '2',
        name: 'AssetTp'
      },
      position: {
        x: 212.000000,
        y: 212.000000
      },
      style: {
        'width': '400.000000'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '13',
        name: 'CLnItm'
      },
      position: {
        x: 112.000000,
        y: 312.000000
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '8',
        name: 'UoM'
      },
      position: {
        x: 312.000000,
        y: 412.000000
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '2-8',
        source: '2',
        target: '8'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '2-13',
        source: '2',
        target: '13'
      }
    }
  ],
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'shape': 'rectangle',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-size': '12',
        'width': '60',
        'label': 'data(name)'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 2,
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: 'preset'
  }
});

/*
    I want to set the edge ('2-8') between 
    AssetTp(2) and UoM(8) to be vertical. 
  This is my draft to show my intent.
    This is hard-coded for simplicity--these
    calculations would of course be performed
    in a function.
    There are likely many syntax errors.
*/
let e28 = cy.$('#2-8');
//  Get that edge's target node's bounding box
let tbbox = e28.target().boundingBox();
//  Get that edge's current target endpoint
let e28TargetPos = e28.targetEndpoint();
//  Calculate the edge's new target coordinates
let e28TargetX = tbbox.x1 + (tbbox.w / 2);
let e28TargetY = e28TargetPos.y;
//  Following the same pattern, get the source node details
let sbbox = e28.source().boundingBox();
let e28SourcePos = e28.sourceEndpoint();
/*  Calculate the new source coordinates
    Position the edge's source x coordinate directly above
    its target x coordinate.
*/
let e28SourceX = e28TargetX;
let e28SourceY = e28SourcePos.y;
//  The heart of my question: how to assign these new
//  values to edge e28? This next line is entirely speculative.

// e28Pos.set(e28SourceX, e28SourceY, e28TargetX, e28TargetY);
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add more code to your question, that way we can help you in a more constructive way.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you Stephan for motivating me to provide this MRE.

Comment: I think you just need to set the initial positions of your nodes correctly. The point in using a preset layout is to position everything the way you want to. Why are you trying to move edges around if you can easily set these edge endpoints by having the nodes in the correct place.

Comment: Stephan, I can't fully explain in this forum why node positioning isn't the solution to this problem.  Please take it as given that the nodes are where they are and that I need to reposition the edges. My question is how can I do that? Do I have to destroy the original edge and add a new one? Or can I update the  values on the existing edge? Or...?  Thanks, Mike.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use the animate function to move the nodes after layout rendering occured: `cy.nodes(**identifier here**).animate(position: { x: xPos, y: yPos })`

If that is something you'd like to see I can post an answer below with an MRE.

Comment: Yes I'd appreciate seeing that option. Could you also comment on the idea of deleting  an edge, then creating a new one with the two (x,y) coordinates? Is that feasible? And, again, thank you for your response. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Another idea: can I create a tiny, transparent node for, for example, the AssetTp end of the edge between AssetTp and ClnItm, then position that new node below AssetTp but in the position I want it? Would that work?

Comment: This is appreciated. Now I know what I can and can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving edges is, as far as I know, not possible. The edges always point to a node, so moving the node is the way to go. Removing an edge and adding a new one won't change the position of the node. I added an MRE showing you a way to move a node (and subsequently the connected edge(s):

```js
// get the source and target node
let AssetTp = cy.$('#2');
let CLnltm = cy.$('#13');

// calculate the desired position based off the nodes
let xPos = AssetTp.boundingBox().x1 + (AssetTp.width() / 2);
let yPos = CLnltm.position('y');

// move the target node with .animate()
CLnltm.animate(
  { position: { x: xPos, y: yPos } }, 
  { duration: 1000 },
);
```

Here is the working MRE:

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [{
      data: {
        id: '2',
        name: 'AssetTp'
      },
      position: {
        x: 212.000000,
        y: 212.000000
      },
      style: {
        'width': '400.000000'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '13',
        name: 'CLnItm'
      },
      position: {
        x: 112.000000,
        y: 312.000000
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '8',
        name: 'UoM'
      },
      position: {
        x: 312.000000,
        y: 412.000000
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '2-8',
        source: '2',
        target: '8'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: '2-13',
        source: '2',
        target: '13'
      }
    }
  ],
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'shape': 'rectangle',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-size': '12',
        'width': '60',
        'label': 'data(name)'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 2,
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: 'preset'
  }
});

cy.off('layoutready');
cy.ready(() => {
  let AssetTp = cy.$('#2');
  let CLnltm = cy.$('#13');

  let xPos = AssetTp.boundingBox().x1 + (AssetTp.width() / 2);
  let yPos = CLnltm.position('y');
  CLnltm.animate({
    position: {
      x: xPos,
      y: yPos,
    },
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```